# uglify not working in gulp for js files

Tags: javascript, gulp, uglifyjs

I used for the js file but it didn't work. I used same scenario for the minimize css file. It works properly. How can I overcome that problem?

```
gulp.task('buildApp',['copyAll'],function(){ //concatenate js files to buildApp
    return gulp.src(paths.js)
        .pipe(depsOrder())
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename('app.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.buildAppconcat))

});
```

Comment: Any error message? What output do you get in your destination directory?

Comment: did n't show any error message.Case it did n't  show min js version.It shown existing full code with out minimizing

Comment: import gulp-util as gutil `gutil = require 'gulp-util'` and add an error handler `.on 'error', gutil.log`

Comment: Did you try to output the concatenated file before uglifying it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's seems that you want to save two files **app.js** and **app.min.js**. For this scenario you could do the following:

```
gulp.task('buildApp',['copyAll'],function(){ //concatenate js files to buildApp
return gulp.src(paths.js)
    .pipe(depsOrder())
    .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.buildAppconcat))
    .pipe(rename('app.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.buildAppconcat))

});
```